# What kind of Alert Dilouge is used in instagram

Tags: android, instagram, android-alertdialog

Hello im wondreing that what kind of alert dilougebox does instagram uses (i dont even know that is it a alert dilouge box or something else ) ,where if you hold on a post in a profile it shows in window (image or video) ,i want to implement that kind of fuctionality but with list of action button

and aslo one more thing that does this comes in material design guidlines or not

here a screen shot of what im talking about

[image]

Comment: That is not a dialog Box . It is a simple CardView with ImageView and several Buttons below . You just need to have such a layout and have a LongTouchListener attached so you know when to display the image and when to discard it

Comment: how can i implement that kind of fuctionality of displaying a cardview and also blurr the background layout can you please provide me any resource if possible

Comment: To achieve such king of behaviour you have to create a custom layout of your own . That layout must have a ImageViewand rest of the layout you need to blur it .You can use library to do that for eg .https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry. So you have to set a onTouch Listener on your recylcerview or a LongClikListener , so on MotionEvent.ActionDown you need make the custom layout visible and MotionEvent.ActionUp(that is when finger is lifted of the screen) you need to make this layout gone